# Multiple PreConditions

Tags: liquibase

I am implementing a changeset in `Liquibase` that needs a few different preconditions to be valid before it attempts to run.

Scenario #1: **If table A,B,C exists, mark as ran**

Scenario #2: **If table X,Y,Z doesn't exist, halt execution of changeset**

In other words, I need two `<preConditions>` tags with different `onFail` clauses. Is this at all allowed in Liquibase? I can't seem to make it work. The [docs](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) aren't very informative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not allowed currently. There can be just one  block.

Would it work to break it up into two separate changeSets?

Comment: I need to create table A on legacy DB. That table has foreign key to other schema's table B id. If table A already exists - MARK_RAN. If not exists - check B exists and mark onFail SKIP

Answer (score 3):

Combine them with `<or>` or `<and>` like this:

```
<preConditions>
    <or>
        <runningAs username="liquibase" />
        <runningAs username="sa" />
    </or>
</preConditions>
```

[Here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) is some documentation on preConditions.

Comment: I am already doing this, but this doesn't really address my question. How can I set two different `onFail` clauses?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Didn't see that. Now that you edited the question it's clear, but unfortunately I don't have an answer.

Comment: What does actually happen if you put 2 `preConditions` in the changeset. Without any logical `<or>` and then define the `onFail` clauses? Skimming the source code of the `liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXHandler` I can't see that this might not be allowed. Though I certainly don't oversee the complete logic of the changelog parser.

Comment: It is not allowed currently. There can be just one <preConditions> block. 

Would it work to break it up into two separate changeSets?

Comment: If it's not currently allowed, I got my answer =) Thanks! @NathanVoxland - please add this as an answer, so I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround that I've simply used:

- create a normal precondition

  ```
  <!-- pre-condition tests -->
  <preConditions onFail="WARN">
          <runningAs username="${db.maintenance.user}" />
  </preConditions>
  ```
- create an empty `changeSet` for another *onFail* level

  ```
  <changeSet id="liquibase-pre-1" author="liquibase" runAlways="true" runOnChange="true" runInTransaction="false">
      <preConditions onFail="HALT" onFailMessage="...">
          <!-- ... -->
      </preConditions>
      <sql>
          select 1 <!-- (Postgresql) or "select 1 from dual" (Oracle) -->
      </sql>
  </changeSet>
  ```